# Brother printer - long pause between files in queue (MacOS, Wi-Fi)

Tags: printer, brother-printer

---

MacOS 10.14
Brother HL-L2340DWR connected via Wi-Fi

Printer has long pause between two files in print queue.

After the printer has printed a file from the queue:

- printer shows message on display `Ready`
- in queue window in MacOS under the printed file is displayed message `Printing - pending job completion` about 10 seconds and **nothing happens**.

Why such pause between printing two files? (Files is about 50Kb, several lines of text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

You need add printer by ip (don't use Bonjour) with LPD protocol and Brother CUPS driver.

Now printing speed like via USB.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS 12.5.1 Brother HL-L2340DWR connected via Wi-Fi

Same issue.

There is no driver for MacOS 12.x on the Brother website, but [the driver for macOS 10.15.x](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2340dw_us_eu_as&os=10060) 27/09/2019
(1.5.0) works well, even with Bonjour.

[image]
[image]